# @font-face in IE with modal window: once in the modal font reverts back to Helvetica

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iframe, modal-dialog, font-face

I'm using @font-face and it's working perfectly even in IE when loading the index page. However, when I open my modal window using IE it still works and then I click on a link within the modal to display a new page in the modal - it reverts to Helvetica on that page, on the previous page and even when I close the modal my index is now in Helvetica. Even more strange is I have Georgia/serif set as my base font in the CSS. If anyone is familiar with this or has a link to a page with info I'd be grateful. I'd rather not give a link to the working page/code at the moment but if anyone is immediately familiar with this problem etc. that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: I also just tried putting the @font-face css declaration directly on the html of each page and it still does it.

Answer (score 0):

If the modal is in an IFRAME, it will need to have a reference to your CSS file as well.

Comment: All the pages loading in the modal reference the css - is there somewhere else I need to reference the css?

Comment: No, as long as those pages do as well you should at least see Georgia in the modal windows. And I haven't worked with @font-face enough to know if that's the cause, probably shouldn't have opened my yap.

Comment: :) Thanks anyway for taking the time.